# What steps do I need to take to replace my Apple TV 4 remote?

Tags: appletv

We broke our Apple TV 4 remote, and bought a replacement. However, the new one does not appear to control the Apple TV. Do I need to take any steps to get the new remote to control my existing Apple TV 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the old Apple TV Remote is out of Bluetooth range, then while in front of the Apple TV set top box press a button on the new remote. This should pair the remote to the Apple TV.

If not, try pressing Volume Up and Menu simultaneously on both remotes for 2-3 seconds, new and old, then do the aforementioned steps again with the new remote.

Comment: Pressing Volume Up and Menu at the same time in front of the Apple TV on the new remote did the trick. For good measure, I put the old remote as far as I could in the back yard. :) Thanks so much!